# How to stop counting of timeout automatically if command finishes earlier?

Tags: command-line, timeout

In my script I'm using timeout to set a maximum timelimit for executing a command.

```
start 7z.exe t %%f
if errorlevel 2 (DEL %%f & echo File broken. Reload File!)
timeout /t 3600
```

If the execution lasts longer than an hour the timeout should break the execution. That's working without any problems.

But how can I ignore the timeout counting and proceed my script **automatically** if the command finishes before the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

As curretly written, [`start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) without `/W` switch does not affect/change  `errorlevel`! **Proof**:

```
==> hfhgf
'hfhgf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

==> echo %errorlevel%
9009

==> start "" ping.exe localhost

==> echo %errorlevel%
9009

==> start "" /W ping.exe localhost

==> echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Use `/W` or `/WAIT` switch (start application and wait for it to terminate) and remove all that `timeout` line as follows. I guess that your code snippet could be `do` part of a `for` loop:

```
for %%f in (*.zip) do (
  (call )
  start "" /W 7z.exe t "%%f"
  if errorlevel 2 (
     echo File broken. Reload File %%f
     DEL "%%f"
  )
)
```

On `(call )` explanation, see Dave Benham's reply to [*setting ERRORLEVEL to 0* question](https://superuser.com/a/649329/376602):

> If you want to force the errorlevel to 0, then you can use this
>   totally non-intuitive, but very effective syntax: `(call )`. The space
>   after *call* is critical. If you want to set the errorlevel to 1, you
>   can use `(call)`. It is critical that there not be any space after
>   *call*.